# Change the DataSource of a Microsoft.Reporting.Winforms.ServerReport

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I've searched around and what I want to do doesn't seem possible, however I just want to clarify.

Is it possible to change the DataSource of a ServerReport. So if I have a ReportViewer I want to be able to define the DataSource the report uses from an available list of shared DataSources defined on the server.

I would like to do this so that I don't have to maintain multiple report server instances for each database engine instances. Is this crazy?

I'm using SSRS 2008 on a Win2k3 server and my project is a .NET 3.5 Win Forms project.

Anybody have any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way to achieve this is to run the ReportViewer control in Local Processing mode.  That way, it will be not require a database connection at all.

Comment: OK, I'm seeing if there is a way to download a server report and process it locally, doesn't seem possible. I'm sure what I'm proposing to do doesn't seem that crazy.

Comment: Like I said, you can retrieve your dataset from your datasource, and feed it to the reportviewer control in local processing mode.  I do this, and it does work.  You don't have to generate the report on the server.

Comment: However that means I have to distribute the reports locally, right?